# Does Log.sendLogAsync() have limitations?

Tags: codenameone

Does `Log.sendLogAsync()` API have limitations in the number of requests or any other limitation of usage? I know that it works only for Pro accounts.

I've noticed that when it's invoked dozens of times by one of my apps in a short time, it stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's a 100 messages per day limit on sending logs to avoid potential spam flooding.